# Why is it necessary to call dispatch_group_leave the same number of times as dispatch_group_enter?

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

In my dispatch_group code, I use dispatch_group_wait to time out a group of web service calls.
Question, it seems like I would need to count how many times dispatch_group_enter is called and then call the same number of remaining dispatch_group_leave should some web service calls never return causing an unequal number of dispatch_group_enter vs dispatch_group_leave.  Why?

I have seen crashes happening if I don't do this in the case when timeout happens and triggers dispatch_group_wait.  The crash goes away as soon as make sure dispatch_group_enter/dispatch_group_leave match their call count.

```
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

for (...) {

  dispatch_group_enter(group);

  // Make backend call and upon return call dispatch_group_leave
  [self backendCallWithCompletionHandler:^(id results) {
     dispatch_group_leave(group);
  }

}

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            dispatch_group_wait(self.group, dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 
(int64_t)(self.timeoutInterval * NSEC_PER_SEC)));
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                //execute stuff on main thread
                // call remaining dispatch_group_leave here if dispatch_group_enter and dispatch_group_leave count don't match?
            });
    });
```

Comment: Do you have some path of execution in `backendCallWithCompletionHandler` that might not result in having the completion block called? Generally, you'd want to make sure that the completion block is always called (but provide a parameter to the block that can differentiate between success or failure) or have a second block parameter for failure (in which you could leave the group in that situation). But as long as your `enter` and `leave` are balanced like this, you definitely don't have to keep track of the number of calls (the group does that for you).

Comment: In terms of its crashing if the `dispatch_group_wait` times out, you'd have to share with us some of the particulars about that crash (stack trace, perhaps add exception breakpoint so you can identify where it's crashing, more info about what you're doing in that final block after the `dispatch_group_wait`, etc.), for us to comment about that. There's not enough here for us to diagnose why it would crash upon timeout. But it's not the fact that the `dispatch_group_wait` timed-out that is causing the crash, but rather likely something you're doing after the timeout occurs.

Comment: As a final aside, I'd personally prefer to see `backendCallWithCompletionHandler` employ the appropriate timeout logic for the individual requests, and then replace this `dispatch_group_wait` logic with a simple `dispatch_group_notify`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Quite interesting. I tested the following simple code with Xcode 5.1.1 on OS X 10.9.4.

```
/* test.m */
#include <dispatch/dispatch.h>

int main()
{
    {
        dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
        dispatch_group_enter(group);
        //dispatch_group_leave(group);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled the Objective-C code with ARC.

```
$ clang -O0 -g -fobjc-arc a.m
```

Executed the program.

```
$ ./a.out
illegal hardware instruction ./a.out
```

The program was crashed. If dispatch_group_leave(group) was called (enter and leave are all ballanced), there are no exceptions at all. Got the detail of the crash using lldb.

```
$ lldb a.out
Current executable set to 'a.out' (x86_64).
(lldb) run
Process 73482 launched: 'a.out' (x86_64)
Process 73482 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0x3808a1, 0x00007fff87125287 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_semaphore_dispose + 55, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
    frame #0: 0x00007fff87125287 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_semaphore_dispose + 55
libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_semaphore_dispose + 55:
-> 0x7fff87125287:  ud2    
   0x7fff87125289:  leaq   0x103b9(%rip), %rcx       ; "BUG IN LIBDISPATCH: flawed group/semaphore logic"
   0x7fff87125290:  movq   %rcx, -0x104f9b1f(%rip)   ; gCRAnnotations + 8
   0x7fff87125297:  ud2    
(lldb)
```

The exception was occurred at _dispatch_semaphore_dispose. We can luckily read libdispatch source code at Apple OpenSource site. Take a look at http://opensource.apple.com/source/libdispatch/libdispatch-339.92.1/src/semaphore.c

```
void
_dispatch_semaphore_dispose(dispatch_object_t dou)
{
    dispatch_semaphore_t dsema = dou._dsema;

    if (dsema->dsema_value < dsema->dsema_orig) {
        DISPATCH_CLIENT_CRASH(
                "Semaphore/group object deallocated while in use");
    }
```

According to this source code, dispatch_group uses dispatch_semaphore. And dispatch_semaphore forces calling signal/wait must be ballanced.

dispatch_semaphore_create manual:

```
CAVEATS
     Unbalanced dispatch semaphores cannot be released.  For a given sema-
     phore, calls to dispatch_semaphore_signal() and dispatch_semaphore_wait()
     must be balanced before dispatch_release() is called on it.
```

Thus, calling dispatch_group_enter and dispatch_group_leave must be balanced as well.