# dispatch_group_t - EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

This is my first time using `dispatch_group_t` and I'm making a simple mistake. `dispatch_group_notify` is getting called before any of the async calls are returning therefore before even the first `dispatch_group_leave(group)`, which then throws a `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION`.

However, I don't know why this is happening.

```
dispatch_queue_t queue =      dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
    [self getCategoriesMainWithParameters:nil withSuccess:^(NSArray *objects) {
        [categoriesMain addObjectsFromArray:objects];
        dispatch_group_leave(group);
    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
        groupError = error;
        dispatch_group_leave(group);
    }];
});

dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
    [self getCategoriesSubWithParameters:nil withSuccess:^(NSArray *objects) {
        [categoriesSub addObjectsFromArray:objects];
        dispatch_group_leave(group);
    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
        groupError = error;
        dispatch_group_leave(group);
    }];
});

dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
    [self getCategoriesProductWithParameters:nil withSuccess:^(NSArray *objects) {
        [categoriesProduct addObjectsFromArray:objects];
        dispatch_group_leave(group);
    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
        groupError = error;
        dispatch_group_leave(group);
    }];
});

dispatch_group_notify(group,dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
   ...
});
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/25433076/629118 I explained the "under the hood".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function `dispatch_group_async` automatically “enters” the group when the block is dispatched, and automatically “leaves” when the dispatched block finishes. But you are calling `dispatch_group_leave` again, so you end up with too many “leave” calls, resulting in the error you describe.

One should either call `dispatch_group_async` (with all the “enter” and “leave” calls made for you), or manually call `dispatch_group_enter` before the async call and calling `dispatch_group_leave` in the completion handler of the asynchronous process.

In this case, because you are calling an asynchronous task inside the dispatched block, the `dispatch_group_async` pattern won’t work. You want to manually `dispatch_group_enter` before calling the asynchronous method and then having the completion handler call `dispatch_group_leave`, as you have. The group will be notified when every “enter” is matched by a “leave”. And because the method that you are calling is already asynchronous, you don’t need to use `dispatch_async` or `dispatch_group_async` at all.

Thus, it might look like:

```
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

dispatch_group_enter(group);
[self getCategoriesMainWithParameters:nil withSuccess:^(NSArray *objects) {
    [categoriesMain addObjectsFromArray:objects];
    dispatch_group_leave(group);
} failure:^(NSError *error) {
    groupError = error;
    dispatch_group_leave(group);
}];

dispatch_group_enter(group);
[self getCategoriesSubWithParameters:nil withSuccess:^(NSArray *objects) {
    [categoriesSub addObjectsFromArray:objects];
    dispatch_group_leave(group);
} failure:^(NSError *error) {
    groupError = error;
    dispatch_group_leave(group);
}];

dispatch_group_enter(group);
[self getCategoriesProductWithParameters:nil withSuccess:^(NSArray *objects) {
    [categoriesProduct addObjectsFromArray:objects];
    dispatch_group_leave(group);
} failure:^(NSError *error) {
    groupError = error;
    dispatch_group_leave(group);
}];

dispatch_group_notify(group,dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
    ...
});
```

Comment: Why do you need `queue` here then?

Comment: You don't. It was left over from the original code snippet. I've removed it.

Comment: This also manifests if you leave the dispatch group more times than you've entered it. Don't forget to remove your testing/stub/temporary code ;)

Comment: @RndmTsk - Absolutely. That is the root cause of the problem here, because `dispatch_group_async` automatically “enters” _and_ “leaves”, so the extra `dispatch_group_leave` (without a corresponding `dispatch_group_enter`) in the OP’s original code snippet resulted in too many “leave” calls. I’ve tried to clarify my answer.